# What is the best way to show multiple files to an reviewer?

Tags: website-design, gui-design

Say you have emails with resumes for a job position and applicants have multiple files attached with their emails. The current view of the web app is like similar to the picture below where users need to click on each and every attachment to view it. Viewing the attachment is the main task, and if liked, user needs to take an action that marks the mail "selected" (guessing button click).

[image: view]

How can I make attachment viewing efficient while providing enough real estate to view the attachment and email simultaneously?

Comment: So you want to be able to view attachment and the email at the same time?

Comment: @ChairmanMeow yes. edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is obviously space, how about taking a leaf out Microsoft outlook and having a preview pane?

[image: Preview Pane]

The Message and attachment (Icon and file name) act as tab headings so you can easily switch between.

Comment: thanks ... but as you have rightly mentioned space is the biggest issue. the middle pane becomes really small when the preview pane slides out.

Comment: If you take the idea of tabs maybe you could have a tab between the message Mail and Inbox and have attachment shown?